# How to set the display value and the value of autocompleted textbox?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, autocomplete

I've made an auto-completion in a textbox using Jquery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchCollabo').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteCollabo")'
    });
});
```

So the data come from the method **AutocompleteCollabo** which looks like that:

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteCollabo(string term)
    {
        int NumDossier = StructureData.DonneNumDossier((string)Session["NumCRPCEN"], (string)Session["MotDePasse"]);
        List<Contact> ListeContacts = StructureData.DonneListeElementDossier(NumDossier);
        Contact[] tabContacts = new Contact[ListeContacts.Count()];
        int count = 0;
        foreach (Contact contact in ListeContacts)
        {
            tabContacts[count] = contact;
            count++;
        }
        var collaborateurs = tabContacts;

        var collaborateurFiltres = collaborateurs.Where(
            item => item.Nom.Contains(term) || item.Fonction.Contains(term)
            );
        return Json(collaborateurFiltres, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The returned json contains a list of object as below:

```
[{"ListeFonctions":[],"IdContact":91264,"Nom":"solecki","Prenom":"hubert","Email":"hsolecki@mail.c"}]
```

Now I would like to set the display name (Name + function) and the value which I want to get when I select a row of the auto-completion. Do you have an Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it, it may help. 
The function that I'm calling throught an Ajax call:

```
public ActionResult AutocompleteCollabo(string term)
    {
        int NumDossier = StructureData.DonneNumDossier((string)Session["NumCRPCEN"], (string)Session["MotDePasse"]);
        List<Contact> ListeContacts = StructureData.DonneListeElementDossier(NumDossier);
        var tabContactFull = ListeContacts.Where(contact => contact.Nom.Contains(term) || contact.Prenom.Contains(term) || contact.Fonction.Contains(term));
        var tabInfosUtiles = tabContactFull.Select(contact => new { label = contact.Nom + " " + contact.Prenom + " ("+contact.Fonction+") ", value = contact.Nom + " " + contact.Prenom + " ("+contact.Fonction+") ", id = contact.IdContact }).ToArray();
        // We set our needed informations with a title like "Label", "Value"
        // So the auto-complete can find by itself which data to display and which are for the value 
        return Json(tabInfosUtiles, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My Ajax call and the success event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchCollabo').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("AutocompleteCollabo")',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#idElement").val(ui.item.id);
            // If you want to get the value : ui.item.Value
            // If you want to get the label : ui.item.Label
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps some of you !